# Choosing available docker image tag for deployment

Tags: teamcity

Currently, I am specifying the docker image tag version from my config parameter prompt every time i want to deploy my docker image to a specific env. I need to double check the container registry for the image version to supply in the param.

Is there a way to dynamically get the image versions from the repo? Or the recommended flow so that I can eliminate the manual step of checking the available version that can be deployed?

Answer (score 0):

I am typically getting the image versions from the repository in the following way. I create a dummy **Configuration Parameter**, e.g. `docker-image-version` and set any dummy value there (e.g. `test-version`). Be sure to not make this parameter read-only.

Then I parse the version from the repository (in my case using Groovy with the help of the [Groovy runner plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10468-groovy-script-teamgroovy-), but it can be in any language of course), and post the [service message](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html#Adding+or+Changing+a+Build+Parameter) to TeamCity to modify the `docker-image-version` parameter value.

The code in Groovy looks as follows (in my case it's parsing the version from Maven's POM file):

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(basedir.getAbsolutePath() + "/pom.xml")
def version = xml.version
println "Detected version: ${version}"
println "##teamcity[setParameter name='docker-image-version' value='${version}']"
```

Then you are able to use `%docker-image-version%` parameter reference in the consequent build steps.